# Rails keeps showing "UnkownAttributeError" while trying to insert into two tables from one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

What I wanted to do is get the

> last_insert_id

of a table and insert it into another table but I get this error while doing it this way(I don't know if this is the right way to do such things)

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'content' for MessagePicture.): # This is copied from the console
>   unknown attribute 'content' for MessagePicture. # Copied from the Browser and it had this number highlighted
>
> @message = current_user.messages.build.message_pictures.build(message_params)

This is the

> new and create methods of the Message_controller class

```
def new
    @message = current_user.messages.build if logged_in?
    @reciever = User.find_by(params[:id])
  end



def create
    #@msg = Message.new(user_params)
    @message = current_user.messages.build.message_pictures.build(message_params)

    if @message.save
      if @message[:picture].present?
        # Send this to the message model for insertion with the @message_id and from the picture model, insert it to the
        add_msg_pic(msg = [@message.id,@message[:msg_img_url]])
      end

      flash[:success] = "Message sent"
      redirect_to messages_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Message not sent"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This is the

> message_params method

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:content, :receiver, :sender, :archive, message_pictures_attributes:[:msg_img_url, :message_id])
end
```

This is the

> Message class(model) add_msg_pic method

```
def add_msg_pic(msg)
    msg.message_pictures.each.do |m|
    m.message.id = nil
    message_pictures << m
end

This is the view page
<h1>Compose a new message</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@message, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @message %>

          <%= f.label :content %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :receiver, value: @reciever %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :sender, value: current_user.id %>
          <%= f.text_area :content, size:"20x15" %>
          <%= f.submit "Send message", class: "btn btn-primary" %> 

          <span class="picture">
            <%= f.fields_for :message_pictures do |mp| %>
              <%= mp.file_field :msg_img_url, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
            <% end %>   
          </span>
        <% end %>
        <%= button_to "Save message", archive_messages_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Message` looks like this

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_pictures
end
```

Then this:

```
@message = current_user.messages.build.message_pictures.build(message_params)
```

should actually be

```
@message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
```

Right now you are passing all of those attributes to a new `MessagePicture` but really you should be passing some to the `Message` and some to the `MessagePicture`.

The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will slice off the ones for `message_pictures` via `message_pictures_attributes` and build both items for you.

Comment: Doing it as described above by you makes the choose file button to disappear

Comment: @gbengawale this has nothing to do with your view this is in the controller code for create so I do not understand the comment. The above will solve the error you are receiving which is what the question/answer is based on